# getting specific data in range of 1-10 from dict

Tags: python-3.x

Im fairly new to programming and came upon a work-related problem(nothing to do with computers or any)
and thought i could automaticly calculate this for my employees.

update:

It needs to scan through the dict keys and find the number related to the input:

For example input 289:
Search through Dict keys

271: 1393.289,  # 7.5505
**281: 1468.817,  # 7.5735**
291: 1544.574,  # 7.5962
301: 1620.559,  # 7.6188

289 is between 281 and 291

Take value of 281 which is 1468.817(use this as base value)
289-281 = 8, so remainder of 8 is then multiplied by 7.5735(the [1] index of the dict) then return value of base + remainder * 7.5735 = 1.529,405

the value that we need to multiple remainder with changes on every new dict key

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully comprehend what you are trying to do, but if I understand correctly you are processing a user input with a special function that will yield a result 'base' in the range of 0 to 320.  Using this computed base you then want to select a key from a dictionary basisIJK such that key-1 <= key < key+1.  Having identified the appropriate basisIJK dictionary key you want to return key + (base-key)* basisIJK[key][1].
If my understanding is correct you can do the following:

```
basisIJK = {271 : [1393.289, 7.5505], 281 : [1468.817, 7.5735], 291 : [1544.574, 7.5962], 301 : [1620.559, 7.6188]}

def find_value(n, d):
    kys = sorted(list(d.keys()))
    for i in range(1, len(kys)):
        if kys[i-1] <= n and n < kys[i]:
            r = d[kys[i-1]][0] + (n - kys[i-1]) * d[kys[i-1]][1]
            return r
    return None
```

executing

```
find_value(289, basisIJK)
```

Yields

```
1529.405
```

Comment: i updated question, the output value of find_value(286, basisIJK) here should be 1.506,684, base value of 281(1468.817) + remainder(281-286) * 7.5735([1] index of dict belonging to 281)

Comment: So what part of my logic is inconsistent with this?  I don't see where it differs, what am i missing?